# python3 insert a variable value in the command

Tags: python-3.x, excel, variables, insert, command

```
#Import the xlrd module

import xlrd

#set the location of the file you want to analyze:

loc = ("pivot.xlsx")

#identify it was as an Excel workbook

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

#select the sheet you want to review

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

#we can read a particular cell's value:

sheet.cell_value(0,0)

#Count the total number of rows:

r1 = sheet.nrows
r1 = r1 - 1
print(r1)
print(sheet.nrows)

print(sheet.nrows)

# Count the total number of columns:

c1 = sheet.ncols
print(c1)
print(sheet.ncols)


m1 = "chart.add_series({'name':'No. of Transactions', 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$**6**', 'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$**6**', 'data_labels':{'value':True,'category': True,'legend_key': True,'leader_lines': True,'category_name': True,'percentage': True,'position': 'outside_end'}})"

print(m1)
```

The value of `r1` here is `7`.

I want to replace

```
'=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$**6**'
```

with the value

```
'=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$**r1**'
```

so that it is

```
'=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$**7**'
```

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For python3.6 or greater you could use

```
f'=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$**{r1}**'
```

Comment: m1 = "chart.add_series({'name':'No. of Transactions', 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6', 'values': '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6', 'data_labels':{'value':True,'category': True,'legend_key': True,'leader_lines': True,'category_name': True,'percentage': True,'position': 'outside_end'}})"

print(m1)

Comment: I want to replace 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6 with the variable"r1" in 'categories': '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$r1